# How to Join two tables in App Script and fetch the data into big query existing table

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

Is their a simple way to join two tables in google big query using a google app script and save the results in a existing table in the same project folder on google big query.

```
function saveQueryToTable1() {
  var projectId = 'instagram-1314';
  var datasetId = 'Divya_Test';
  var tableId = 'Join';
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: '((SELECT * FROM [instagram-1314:Divya_Test.Join1_Test]) UNION (SELECT * FROM [instagram-1314:Divya_Test.Join2_Test]))' ,
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
       }
      }
    }
 };

 var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
 Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
```

I tried the above Code but it didn't work. Can anyone please help me out with this or have any ideas if this is possible? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in BigQuery Legacy SQL (that you are using in your example) there is no UNION keyword - rather you should use comma for this as in example below

```
((SELECT * FROM [instagram-1314:Divya_Test.Join1_Test], [instagram-1314:Divya_Test.Join2_Test]))
```

See [FROM clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from) for more details on this

Above approach will cost you two scans (both tables) with $5 per TB. If you have small tables you most likely don't worry

If your tables are big, but of same schema (as it sounds like from the example)  - you can consider using copy vs. query. Copy is $ free.

See more for [Jobs: insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) where you can use [configuration.copy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.copy) instead of [configuration.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query) as you have now in your example